# Add right to left language text to the custom position of existing pdf file by iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Hi
I want to add a text in persian language (a right to left language) to the top of an existing pdf file, using iTextSharp Version 5.0.0.0 library.

I use this code:

```
public static void InsertText(string SourceFileName, string TargetFileName, string Text, int x, int y)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SourceFileName);            
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // open the writer 

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(TargetFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
    document.Open();


    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;  // select the font properties
    FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
    Font fTahoma = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
    writer.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);

    ct.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;            
    Phrase p = new Phrase(Text, fTahoma);
    ct.SetText(p);

    ct.SetSimpleColumn(x, y, x + 350, y + 20);            
    ct.Go();           

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);  // close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)                
        document.NewPage();
    }

    document.Close();
    fs.Close();
    writer.Close();
}
```

I call `InsertText("Source.pdf", "Target.pdf", "Persian message", 10, 800);`
My source.pdf page size is: height: 842,  width: 595

Unfortunately i get target.pdf with only half of my message! The other vertical half is hidden!
Now the question is: How i can add a right to left language text to the top of an existing pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

Problem:  The imported page is probably overwriting the text.

Solution: Add your PdfImportedPage, THEN add the text.